# clean url's Drupal Gallery2

Tags: drupal, gallery

I'm trying to configure my Gallery2 integration in Drupal but i'm stuck at Step 4.

I have to put in two path's to drupal's .htaccess file.

The public path (This is the location of your Drupal .htaccess file relative to your webserver document root.)
Filesystem path (This is the absolute directory path of your Drupal .htaccess file.)

but i have no idea what i have to put where?

My site sits in public_html/5.0, is this the public path?

Answer (score 0):

From manual:
"You may also decide to skip this step in case you dont want/need short URLs for your embedded gallery."

Usually .htaccess for drupal is located where you unpack "drupal....tar.gz".

Try an empty field or ".".

For absolute directory path enter the document root (public_html or public_html/5.0) and execute "pwd" command. You'll receive something like /home/user1/public_html/5.0
This is your absolute path.